# How do operating systems, which do not run on a GUI principle function? Any distinct differences any history behind this?

Tags: operating-systems, gui

*How do they work? 
Please and thanks*
This is for ICT and i cannot find the answer anywhere else

Comment: By not using a GUI. I don't have any clue what your actual question might be?

Comment: sorry i mean, like how do they function

Comment: The same way as an OS that does have a GUI... but they don't run the GUI program... this is an odd question... any more context?

Comment: Yeah its really odd, this is why im asking

Comment: so are there any distinct differences

Comment: There isn't any strict definition of what constitutes an operating system, but it is typically not a single entity, but a group of related programs. Graphical interface *to* an operating system is a kind of shell (a.k.a. "graphical shell") which allows it to collect users' input and translate it into system calls. In other words, GUI is a means of communicating information to operating system rather than being an integral part of it. I hope you are not appalled by the reaction to your question and will ask it differently so that it is easier to answer.

Comment: *"GUI principle function"* is a senseless combination of words.  GUI is the acronym for graphical user interface.  Interface is the salient term.  Some OSes are modular and permit different or no GUI (which reverts to a text-based interface).  Whereas Microsoft has supposedly integrated the Windows GUI with its kernel.  Text (aka command line interface) is typically considered the opposite of GUI.  Some computers (well as some of the first microcomputers, e.g. MITS Altair 8800) have a hardware front-panel interface of binary indicator lights and switches.

Answer (score 2):

So, before GUI you had typing at the command line, writing, compiling and running programs that would expect the input (in a particular form string of numbers etc) then run and give output on the screen - again text based.

Prior to that there were systems that had an input on punched card and the output would require decoding.

Research early computers and interfaces.

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and hit [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [F1] and you'll know how.